# Progressive Web App (PWA) in a sub-folder

Tags: domains, subdomain

Are there any implications for running a Progressive Web App (PWA) on a sub-folder of a site, rather than the domain's root?

Our site has an existing backend-driven site at the root of the domain, but we'd like to add a PWA for the "app" section that members can use.

The solution I often see is using a sub-domain like "app.example.com" to host the app, but I'd like to stay away from a separate domain if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in my case the PWA app ( shortcut from desktop created from chrome) always pointing to the root of site hosted not the sub folder

Comment: Telling us what you did doesn't answer the question "are there any implications..."

Comment: It sounds like the implications are this it broke the desktop shortcut created from Chrome.